# "Dentro al rumore di questo treno": perché "dentro"?

Tags: prepositions, meaning

Nel testo della canzone "Generale", di Francesco de Gregori, si legge:

> Generale, **queste cinque stelle**, queste cinque lacrime sulla mia pelle, **che senso hanno dentro al rumore di questo treno** [...]?

Non capisco come viene utilizzata la preposizione *dentro* in questo contesto. Qual è il suo significato?

Comment: Il treno è mezzo vuoto e mezzo pieno - metafora della vita? Della storia? Il rumore è metafora (metonimia?) della guerra e delle sue conseguenze (incluso lo stato interiore del generale)? La vera domanda mi sembra che sia: "dentro a" è corretto? [Sì](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/D/dentro-in-dentro-a.shtml), è presente anche in Dante («…ché **dentro a** li occhi suoi ardeva un riso tal, ch'io pensai co' miei toccar lo fondo de la mia gloria e del mio paradiso…»).

Comment: Penso che a volte sia difficile spiegare con esattezza il perché del linguaggio poetico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credo che il vero significato della figura retorica usata nella canzone sia *«dentro questo treno rumoroso»*.

In sé e per sé, `dentro` è qui usato nel suo senso abituale. L'uso di `dentro a` o `dentro di` al posto di `dentro` e basta non è insolito né sbagliato.

La "stranezza", che ovviamente è dovuta al fatto che è un testo poetico o comunque letterario che permette virtuosismi di questo genere, è semmai nell'usare il rumore del treno per indicare il treno rumoroso. Questo tropo è una [metonimia](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/metonimia_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/).